# Bootstrap sass permission denied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, bootstrap-sass

Im getting the following error after I've updated my gemfile and installed the gem:

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/build_info/bootstrap-sass-2.3.1.0.info
>   An error occurred while installing bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install bootstrap-sass -v '2.3.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Running Mac OSX 10.8.3

here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end 

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end 


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end
```

at my wits end, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

File permissions issue, try running with sudo

```
     $sudo bundle install
```